# Unknown name value for Enum exception in concurrent application

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have two grails 2.1.1 application versions running on the same database (SQL Server 2005). Applications are running on different servers. Enum type was introduced in first application.

```
   public enum EnumModeType {
        STARTUP, RUNNING, STOPPED, POSTPONED, FINISHED, NONE
   }
```

Second application started throwing exception "Unknown name value for Enum exceptionEnumModeType.FINISHED" after deploying changes to first application. First application is running correctly. I changed first application to initial version and exceptions in second application disappeared.

**UPDATE:** Exception occurs after second application tries insert string value "FINISHED" to other table. This other table column has String datatype. It'is not defined as Enum.

How this is possible and where is the root cause?

Comment: 2nd app reads "FINISHED" from the column, knows nothing about it and throws?

Comment: what's the problem then?

Comment: I suspect the problem is caused by database contrains. The column is defined as varchar(255) and I am looking for database contraints which could afftect exception. So far no luck. The strangest thing, why problem disappears after I restored first application to initial version.

Comment: Check how the enum value is persisted in the db. Maybe sometimes it is:
`EnumModeType.FINISHED` sometimes simple `FINISHED`. Basically scan the table for values another then listed in the enum when the exception appears again.